# How do you limit the number of items on show in the bootstrap btn-dropdowns

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a search bar with bootstrap and one of the elements is a category list. The problem is at the moment when I press the category button it shows every single category in the list at the same time - making the UI awful! How can I limit the number of concurrent options on show?

This is an example of the problem:

[image]

For example I might just want to show the first 5 options and then have a scroll bar for the rest?

This is the markup used to create what I have so far:

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="/search" method="get">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for an event" name="q" id="q">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
  Dropdown
  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
<% category.sub_categories.each do |sub_category| %>
<li><a href="#"><%= sub_category.name %></a></li>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

A fiddle we are working with to try to show the problem can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/c7vcuLsa/2/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle dude? I have a couple of ideas.

Comment: Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c7vcuLsa/2/ many thanks!

Comment: I am trying Andy check out what I have and see if you can go from there.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just add an overflow to the UL?

http://jsfiddle.net/0Lmjppsz/1/

```
.menu-scroll {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I think it is because the scrollbar gets cut off for whatever reason.  Good job @Mike! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Man--if you can figure out a way to keep the dropdown from closing, I have a pretty neat solution here:

It's from an old [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EMD9P/).

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/c7vcuLsa/4/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $lis = $(".dropdown-menu li").hide();
    $lis.slice(0, 5).show();
    var size_li = $lis.length;
    var x = 5,
    start = 0;
$('#next').click(function () {
    if (start + x < size_li) {
        $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
        start += x;
        $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();
    }
});
$('#prev').click(function () {
    if (start - x >= 0) {
        $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
        start -= x;
        $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();
    }
    });
});
```

It scrolls through the list when you use the Prev and Next buttons, but right now the dropdown closes and I am admittedly a little too tired to play with it right now.

Not sure how good you are with js but this will solve it.  Your situation is a little different because you have input-group.

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/ZS4L7/

Comment: The problem with this is - I want it to literally scroll, I cannot have users having to press next , previous buttons!

Comment: The problem is that you would have to set the overflow of the wrapper around your ul to overflow, and there is no wrapper.