# How do I limit bootstrap dropdown visible item number

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Right now its showing all of the items from my timezoneConstants.js file and it has over 40 of them. How do I limit the amount of items seen.

Code is in react and html and is shown below:

```
        return (
            <div className="header-dropdown-wrap d-none d-md-inline-block ">
                <svg className="header-dropdown-icon" viewBox={ClockIcon.viewBox} width="15">
                    <use xlinkHref="#clock" />
                </svg>

                <Dropdown
                    className="header-dropdown"
                    onMouseOver={() => this.hover(true)}
                    onMouseLeave={() => this.hover(false)}
                    isOpen={this.state.toggle || this.state.hover}
                    toggle={this.toggle}
                >
                    <DropdownToggle>
                        <span>{ this.state.time.format("LTS") }</span>
                    </DropdownToggle>
                    <DropdownMenu modifiers={horizontalMiddleModifier()}>
                        <div className="dropdown-menu-inner-wrap offset-3">
                            {TIMEZONES.map((timezone, idx) => {
                                return (
                                    <DropdownItem key={idx} onClick={() => this.select(timezone.name)}>
                                        {/*<span className="dropdown-item-icon"></span>*/}
                                        <span className="dropdown-item-text">{timezone.offset}</span>
                                    </DropdownItem>
                                );
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </DropdownMenu>
                </Dropdown>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: This might help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088810/how-do-you-limit-the-number-of-items-on-show-in-the-bootstrap-btn-dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088810/how-do-you-limit-the-number-of-items-on-show-in-the-bootstrap-btn-dropdowns)

Comment: Thank you @RobMoll I found something there that helped.